# Minimax problem inversion of sign

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, maxima-minima, programming

Consider the optimization problem with $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, with $f:\mathbb{R}^{2n}\to \mathbb{R}$:

$$
\min_{x}\min_{y} - f(x,y).
$$

If I want to exchange the second minimum with a maximum is this the correct way to do it?

$$
\min_{x}\max_{y}f(x,y),$$

or I need to change also the second minimum into a maximum? Can you  explain the reasoning behind these change of min/max? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\min_{y} - f(x,y) = -\max_{y} f(x,y)$:

$$
\min_{x}\min_{y} - f(x,y) = \min_{x} - \max_{y} f(x,y).
$$
Applying the same rule again, you get $-\max_{x} \max_{y} f(x,y)$. Alternatively, you can do it in one step:

$$
\min_x \min_y - f(x,y) = \min_{x,y} - f(x,y) = - \max_{x,y} f(x,y).
$$